# How to pass variable to scss file on webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I would like define global variable or env on webpack.config.js
and pass variable to  .js or .scss file

I have a define "__basedir" is absolute path

> ```
>       new webpack.DefinePlugin({
>           __basedir: "'" + __dirname + "'",
>
>       }),
> ```

```
  {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            data: "$basedir: '" + __dirname + "';"
        }
    }
```

**On js file is already work**

> require(__basedir + '/public/js/Sortable.min.js');

**but on scss file it doesn't work**

> @import "$__basedir/public/css/include-media/dist/_include-media.scss";

how to fix.
Thanks